# SQL Server - select closest row to 30 minute interval

Tags: sql-server

We are using SQL Server 2016:

This is my current table:

```
countx  RunDateTime
104 7/15/20 0:05
104 7/15/20 0:10
102 7/15/20 0:15
102 7/15/20 0:20
100 7/15/20 0:25
100 7/15/20 0:30
102 7/15/20 0:35
99  7/15/20 0:40
97  7/15/20 0:46
99  7/15/20 0:56
93  7/15/20 1:01
93  7/15/20 1:10
93  7/15/20 1:16
91  7/15/20 1:31
89  7/15/20 1:39
87  7/15/20 1:57
88  7/15/20 2:05
80  7/15/20 2:11
81  7/15/20 2:20
```

I would like only the following results

> ```
> countx    RunDateTime
> 104   7/15/20 0:05
> 100   7/15/20 0:30
> 93    7/15/20 1:01
> 91    7/15/20 1:31
> 88    7/15/20 2:05
> ```

How could I only select rows that are most close to the nearest 30 minute interval?

I only want rows most close to the hour and most close to half hour

For example I only want rows most close to

00:00 and 00:30

01:00 and 01:30

02:00 and 02:30

etc.

I was able to select rows closest to the hour, but I can't figure out how to get data closest to the half hour.  Here is what I tried.

```
SELECT  
       RunDateTime,
       COUNT(DISTINCT id) countxbyhour
FROM (SELECT 
            t.*, 
            MIN(RunDateTime) OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(RunDateTime AS DATE),
            DATEPART(HOUR,RunDateTime)) mintmstmp
      FROM table t) x
WHERE RunDateTime = mintmstmp
GROUP BY RunDateTime
ORDER BY RunDateTime
```

Comment: Sample data is better served as `text`, not images, and best served as DDL and DML statements. What are you expected results here as well? What have *you* tried?

Comment: Thanks, I have improved my question

Comment: Any reason there are not rows in your expected results for 102, 99, 97 ... etc.?

Comment: I'm not sure if you were doing something entirely different from my answer. If you were to add `datepart(minute, RunDateTime) / 30` to your partition then your query should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Table

SELECT * INTO #Table FROM (VALUES
    (104, CAST('7/15/20 0:05' as datetime)),
    (104, '7/15/20 0:10'),
    (102, '7/15/20 0:15'),
    (102, '7/15/20 0:20'),
    (100, '7/15/20 0:25'),
    (100, '7/15/20 0:30'),
    (102, '7/15/20 0:35'),
    (99, '7/15/20 0:40'),
    (97, '7/15/20 0:46'),
    (99, '7/15/20 0:56'),
    (93, '7/15/20 1:01'),
    (93, '7/15/20 1:10'),
    (93, '7/15/20 1:16'),
    (91, '7/15/20 1:31'),
    (89, '7/15/20 1:39'),
    (87, '7/15/20 1:57'),
    (88, '7/15/20 2:05'),
    (80, '7/15/20 2:11'),
    (81, '7/15/20 2:20')
) S(countx, RunDateTime);

SELECT * FROM #Table;

WITH DataSource AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, RunDateTime) >= 30 
            THEN (DATEPART(MINUTE, RunDateTime) - 30) / 30.0
            ELSE DATEPART(MINUTE, RunDateTime) / 30.0
        END FracHalfour
    FROM
        #Table
)
SELECT
    D.countx, D.RunDateTime
FROM
    DataSource D
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            countx,
            MIN(FracHalfour) FracHalfour
        FROM
            DataSource S
        GROUP BY
            countx
    ) S ON
        S.countx = D.countx AND
        S.FracHalfour = D.FracHalfour
ORDER BY
    countx DESC
```

Comment: I used some of your ideas to partition  the date part:

Comment: Glad you found it useful :)

Answer (score 1):

based on Jason's:

```
declare @t table(countx int, RunDateTime datetime);
insert into @t values
(104, '7/15/20 0:05'),
(104, '7/15/20 0:10'),
(102, '7/15/20 0:15'),
(102, '7/15/20 0:20'),
(100, '7/15/20 0:25'),
(100, '7/15/20 0:30'),
(102, '7/15/20 0:35'),
(99,  '7/15/20 0:40'),
(97,  '7/15/20 0:46'),
(99,  '7/15/20 0:56'),
(93,  '7/15/20 1:01'),
(93,  '7/15/20 1:10'),
(93,  '7/15/20 1:16'),
(91,  '7/15/20 1:31'),
(89,  '7/15/20 1:39'),
(87,  '7/15/20 1:57'),
(88,  '7/15/20 2:05'),
(80,  '7/15/20 2:11'),
(81,  '7/15/20 2:20');

WITH CTE AS
(--get data and dif
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY (countx) ORDER BY (CASE WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, RunDateTime) >= 30 
            THEN (DATEPART(MINUTE, RunDateTime) - 30) / 30.0
            ELSE DATEPART(MINUTE, RunDateTime) / 30.0
        END)) as rowno
from @t
)
select *
from 
    CTE
where
    CTE.rowno = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Jason beat me to the punch, but here is my version:

```
SELECT
    t.countx,
    t.RunDateTime
FROM
    test t
WHERE
    DATEPART(minute,t.RunDateTime) BETWEEN 0 AND 5
 OR (DATEPART(minute,t.RunDateTime) > 25 AND DATEPART(minute,t.RunDateTime) < 35)
 OR DATEPART(minute,t.RunDateTime) > 55
```

Answer (score 0):

If by closest you mean first time value after the half-hour mark:

```
with data as (
    select *, row_number() over (
        partition by dateadd(minute, -datepart(minute, RunDateTime) % 30, RunDateTime)
        order by RunDateTime
    ) as rn
    from t
)
select * from data where rn = 1;
```

This is basically truncating the extra minutes by a simple deduction. I'm assuming that there are no (milli)seconds involved.

You could also have it "round" to the nearest half hour by adding fifteen minutes prior to the "truncate" operation and taking the absolute value of the distance:

```
with data as (
select *, row_number() over (
        partition by dateadd(minute, -datepart(minute, shiftedDt) % 30, shiftedDt)
        order by abs(datediff(minute, RunDateTime, dateadd(minute, -datepart(minute, RunDateTime) % 30, RunDateTime))), RunDateTime
    ) as rn
    from t cross apply ( values (dateadd(minute, 15, RunDateTime)) ) as s(shiftedDt)
)
select * from data where rn = 1;
```

Where ties come into play it would take the earlier one. Also, if you were to use this method on your sample data it would return a different set of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I used some of Jasons code for ideas to partition the datepart:

```
select 
RunDateTime,
count(distinct id) Countx
from (
        select t.*,
        min(RunDateTime) over(
        partition by cast(RunDateTime as date),( datepart(hour,RunDateTime)*100+CASE WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, RunDateTime) >= 30 
    THEN 30
    ELSE 00 end )) mintmstmp
        from table t
     ) x
where RunDateTime=mintmstmp
group by RunDateTime
order by RunDateTime
```